# Adding an environment variable for a specific user in wix

Tags: elasticsearch, service, wix, environment-variables

I am building a windows installer which installs ElasticSearch as a windows service. To do that I need to set JAVA_HOME environment variable as SYSTEM vairable to JRE folder inside ElasticSearch using the following component in wix:

```
<Component Id="JAVAHOME" Guid="">
  <CreateFolder />
  <Environment Id="JAVA_HOME"
      Action="set"
      Part="all"
      Name="JAVA_HOME"
      Permanent="no"
      System="yes"
      Value="[ELASTICSEARCH]jre"/>
</Component>
```

However, this variable might have been set to a different path prior to installation. To avoid the conflict, one solution which I could think of is to set this environment variable to a different user. I found this link [Adding user in wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420673/wix-user-element-seems-to-create-a-new-user-profile-on-every-install) which potentially enables me to create a user (e.g. ElasticUser). Utimately I would like to install ElasticSearch service under this user account. I am wondering how could I add JAVA_HOME to this user? Any solution including writing C# program as a custom action is appreciated or running a specific command is appreciated?

Comment: if you are ready for shell scripting why don't you write a shell script to check JAVA_HOME if exists trash it and set the new JAVA_HOME